# Swift - can't make scrollview be able to scroll left?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Im having an odd problem with a scrollview - I have tried doing this in a xib file and programmatically. Basically I 3 textfields that I want to be able to scroll to with my scrollview filling the whole screen.

To do this, I first created a scrollview on my xib and constrained it so it always filled the screen. I then expanded the contentsize to 3 times the size of the view so it should be able to scroll

```
scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width*3, screenSize.height * (50/568))
        scrollView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width * -1.5, self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
        scrollView.addSubview(containerView)
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = false
```

I have 3 textfields named search 1, 2, 3 that I then position within this scrollview like this so they are at different lengths off the screen to the LEFT -

```
search3.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5, screenSize.height * 0.45)
search2.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * -0.5, screenSize.height * 0.45)
search1.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * -1.5, screenSize.height * 0.45)
```

This has worked, meaning I have the first search field 2 views to the left, the other right next to it, etc

Problem is I can only scroll to the RIGHT because I can't seem to move the center of my scrollview off the left so its length expands 3 views to the right. I have tried with this -

```
scrollView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width * -1.5, self.view.frame.height * 0.5)
```

And various other methods creating the view programmatically but it sint working. This is what I get with all the things I need to scroll to far to the right -

[image]

Ive never had this. How can I make it expand the views width to the left?

Comment: Why are you moving the center of your scrollview at all?

Comment: Your question is very confusing but I think you set the center point of your views to negative, meaning, it's not possible to scroll that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the scrollView's contentOffset? According to the docs, contentOffset represent:

> The point at which the origin of the content view is offset from the origin of the scroll view.

If you want your scrollview to start in the middle (can scroll to the left and right) this might work for you with assumption contentView is 3 times the size of the scrollView

```
self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.scrollView.contentSize.width/3 , 0.0f);
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. Im getting same result - can't scroll to the left, extends all to the right